# How to read a non .hcl file in terragrunt to a variable

Tags: terraform, terragrunt

Such a simple thing, yet it seems impossible to do or search for... I just need to simply read file contents into a variable and create a list to for loop through.

file A

```
[
  "0.0.0.0/0",
  "8.8.8.8/32"
]
```

file B

```
[
  "10.0.0.0/8",
  "172.0.0.0/16"
]
```

terragrunt.hcl

```
locals {
  priv_subnets = find_in_parent_folders("fileB")
  pub_subnets  = find_in_parent_folders("fileA")

  all_subnets  = concat(priv_subnets, pub_subnets)
}

...

for cidrs in local.all_subnets: ...

Seems to not be consuming the list correctly... what am I missing?

Thanks
```

Comment: What does "Seems to not be consuming the list correctly" mean? Are there any errors? Is only the for loop not working or the `local.all_subnets` is not showing all the subnets?

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand more... `find_in_parent_folders("fileB")` only locates the file, it does not "consume" the content of the file! What I truly need is a solution that will allow me to save a list of IPs (so we can peer review just that list), and have others reference mulitple lists of subnets (based on their desired source/destination reqs)

Comment: You probably want this: https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/reference/built-in-functions/#terraform-built-in-functions?